# How to build exploded jars using Ant task?

Tags: ant, jboss, jar, ear, exploded

Kindly suggest how to build exploded jars using Ant task?

Thanks.

Comment: what is an exploded jar?

Answer (score 1):

An exploded jar is simply a directory which has the same structure as a jar file. Just use `copy`, for example, to put all the files you want in this directory.